# Custom Role Provider not called. What am I doing wrong?

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc

So I'm trying to create a Hello World custom Role Provider-solution in ASP.NET MVC 4.

Basically I've set  `authentication mode="Windows"` in web.config along with defining a role provider like this:

```
<roleManager enabled="true" defaultProvider="MyRoleProvider">
    <providers>
        <clear />
        <add name="MyRoleProvider"  type="MyProject.Code.MyRoleProvider" />
    </providers>
</roleManager>
```

Then I've decorated the `About` controller method like this:

```
[Authorize(Roles = "SomeRole")]
public ActionResult About()
{ /* ... */ }
```

The custom RoleProvider-class looks like this:

```
namespace MyProject.Code {
public class MyRoleProvider : RoleProvider
{
    public override bool IsUserInRole(string username, string roleName)
    {
        if (roleName == "SomeRole" && username = "Administrator") return true;
        return false;
    }

    public override string[] GetRolesForUser(string username)
    {
        return new string[] { "SomeRole" };
    }

    /* a bunch of other overridden methods simply throwing not implementedException */
}
}
```

Now the thing is I've put a breakpoint on every single executable line of code in `MyRoleProvder` but none are hit. I have tested that breakpoints elsewhere are hit so the debugger is not the problem. Why isn't my code in the role provided executed? I was expecting `IsUserInRole` and/or `GetRolesForUser` to be executed when I navigate to the About-page. Am I wrong? Have I configured something wrong?

Full [web.config](http://pastebin.com/ULDdLwVg) for reference

**edit**: The user is redirected to the login page when the about page is clicked. I now realize this is due to the user actually is not authenticated yet. Authorization naturally happens after authentication. Is IISExpress not providing Windows identity?

Answer (score 1):

As this is the first result in a google search i want to give a solution, maybe for others:

To use the windows identity in IIEExpress you have to activate it in your applicationhost.config , which is located in

*[SolutionDir].vs\config\applicationhost.config*

there you can find the xml tag

```
<configuration>
  <system.webServer>
    <security>
      <authentication>
        <windowsAuthentication enabled="false">
```

change enabled="false" to enabled="true"

and you can use windows authenticatuion in IISExpress

Answer (score 0):

I think your type declaration is incomplete, you should include both the full name and the assembly name.

```
type="MyProject.Code.MyRoleProvider, MyProject"
```

You might also need to set Version, Culture and PublicKeyToken if your assemblies are place in the GAC

Hope this helps

Comment: Providing the project did not help. The Type is correct as it was. But see my update-  I think this is more related to IIS Express or the MembershipProvider, than the RoleProvider